# VBA - looking for solution to my simple dynamic looping sum calculation

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm a novice trying to learn VBA. I've got a looping question: I have a simple set of numbers that are grouped in rows of three. I'm hoping to sum them up individually in column f. How could I create a dynamic range in order to loop through these to get the totals?

layout and workings are below - I don't think I have my dynamic range formula correct either. Any help is gratefully appreciated:

[basic test data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H03lS.jpg)

```
Sub testing1000b()

Dim rng As Range
Dim lAnswer As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim firstrow As Long

Dim addrow As Long

Range("e:f").ClearContents
addrow = 6
firstrow = Range("b" & addrow).Row
lastrow = Range("b" & firstrow).End(xlDown).Row
Range("b & firstrow" & "b & lastrow") = rng
lAnswer = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)
Range("f6").Value = lAnswer

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Sum Up Consecutive Cells

```vb
Sub SumConsecutive()

    Const SourceCol As Long = 2
    Const ResultCol As Long = 6
    Const InitialRow As Long = 6
    Const Consecutive As Long = 3

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim FirstRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Result As Long
    Dim RowDiff As Long

    Columns(ResultCol).ClearContents

    FirstRow = InitialRow
    LastRow = Cells(FirstRow, SourceCol).End(xlDown).Row
    RowDiff = LastRow - FirstRow

    Do Until RowDiff <> Consecutive - 1
        Set rng = Range(Cells(FirstRow, SourceCol), Cells(LastRow, SourceCol))
        Result = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)
        Cells(FirstRow, ResultCol).Value = Result
        FirstRow = Cells(LastRow, SourceCol).End(xlDown).Row
        LastRow = Cells(FirstRow, SourceCol).End(xlDown).Row
        RowDiff = LastRow - FirstRow
    Loop

    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dynamic range with the code bellow.
You need to use [Set] when object is assigned to a variable.

```
Set rng = Range("b" & firstrow & ":" & "b" & lastrow)
```

this is a sample code.

```
Sub testing1000b()

  Dim rng As Range
  Dim lAnswer As Long
  Dim lastrow As Long
  Dim firstrow As Long

  Dim addrow As Long: addrow = 6

  Range("e:f").ClearContents

  firstrow = Range("b" & addrow).Row
  lastrow = Range("b" & firstrow).End(xlDown).Row

  For i = 0 To 3
    Set rng = Range("b" & firstrow & ":" & "b" & lastrow)
    Range("f" & firstrow) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)
    firstrow = Range("b" & lastrow).End(xlDown).Row
    lastrow = Range("b" & firstrow).End(xlDown).Row
  Next i

End Sub
```